# How to call a function when "RPC.allow" is applied?

Tags: volttron

In the ***volttron/platform/store.py*** file, it contains:

```
@ RPC.export
@ RPC.allow ('edit_config_store')
def manage_store (self, identity, config_name, raw_contents, config_type = "raw"):
    contents = process_raw_config (raw_contents, config_type)
    self._add_config_to_store (identity, config_name, raw_contents, contents, config_type,
                                  trigger_callback = True)
```

To call this function from outside, I wrote the code as below.

```
 self.vip.rpc.call (CONFIGURATION_STORE, "manage_store", 'platform.driver', config_name, raw_contents, 'json')
```

The error code is as follows.

```
volttron.platform.jsonrpc.Error: method "manage_store" requires capabilities {'edit_config_store'}, but capability [] was provided for user pnp
```

auth is registered as below.

```
INDEX: 8
{
  "domain": null,
  "address": null,
  "mechanism": "CURVE",
  "credentials": "6vjPXC8ctO8oWkeMXAOe5FsAM9vZD_sg0vkLrstnVFs",
  "groups": [],
  "roles": [],
  "capabilities": {
    "edit_config_store": {
      "identity": "pnp.b"
    }
  },
  "comments": "Automatically added on agent install",
  "user_id": "pnp.b",
  "enabled": true
}
```

How do I fix Capability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a security feature. By default an agent can only update its own config store. So the agent with identity pnp.b can only edit its own config store and not of platform.driver. But you (or whoever has access to run vctl auth command or to directly edit the $VOLTTRON_HOME/auth.json file) can edit config store by giving the pnp.b agent the capability to edit the config store of platform.driver.

The capabilities entry for the agent can be changed to a regular expression that allows pnp.b or platform.driver (Or any other pattern you want). Regular expressions should be enclosed in / For example

```
{
  "domain": null,
  "address": null,
  "mechanism": "CURVE",
  "credentials": "6vjPXC8ctO8oWkeMXAOe5FsAM9vZD_sg0vkLrstnVFs",
  "groups": [],
  "roles": [],
  "capabilities": {
    "edit_config_store": {
      "identity": "/pnp.b|platform.driver/"
    }
  },
  "comments": "Automatically added on agent install",
  "user_id": "pnp.b",
  "enabled": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer.

Referring to your answer, I was correcting auth's capability.

```
    INDEX: 8
{
  "domain": null,
  "address": null,
  "mechanism": "CURVE",
  "credentials": "TG3z7cEa1FnMp_642srvNLyd6HsxTq18xMOg20FFWjE",
  "groups": [],
  "roles": [],
  "capabilities": {
    "edit_config_store": {
      "identity": "/pnp.b|platform.driver/"
    }
  },
  "comments": "Automatically added on agent install",
  "user_id": "pnp.b",
  "enabled": true
}
```

However, it still shows that the agent is not authorized as shown in the log below.

Is it my mistake during correction?
Do you have any comments on this?

Note: I use the volttron 7.0rc branch.

```
2020-04-07 09:09:37,467 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.subsystems.rpc ERROR: unhandled exception in JSON-RPC method 'manage_store':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/volttron7_200331/volttron/platform/vip/agent/subsystems/rpc.py", line 158, in method
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/volttron7_200331/volttron/platform/vip/agent/subsystems/rpc.py", line 283, in checked_method
    raise jsonrpc.exception_from_json(jsonrpc.UNAUTHORIZED, msg)
volttron.platform.jsonrpc.Error: method "manage_store" requires capabilities {'edit_config_store'}, but capability [] was provided for user pnp
```